# Python/MySQL, No errors but data not inserting

Tags: python, mysql

I have a code, shown below that reads 4 lines of data over a serial connection. The data is assigned a variable and then an attempt is made to insert this into a local database. However, once the code has run, there is no new data in the database.

I have inserted print commands in to check that the data is definitely being received over terminal and it is, I have also successfully inserted data into the database via terminal, but that was static values such as 10.0, 10.0, 0, 10.

```
import MySQLdb
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
conn  = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user= "JP", passwd= "password", db= "serialdb")

cursor = conn.cursor()

while 1:

        print "waiting for data"
        print ""

        xs = ser.readline()
        print xs
        time.sleep(1)

        ys = ser.readline()
        print ys
        time.sleep(1)

        zs = ser.readline()
        print zs
        time.sleep(1)

        vs = ser.readline()
        print vs
        time.sleep(1)

        try:
                x= float(xs)
        except ValueError:
                pass
        try:
                y= float(xs)
        except ValueError:
                pass
        try:
                z= float(xs)
        except ValueError:
                pass

        v = int(vs)

        print "inserting into database"
        print ""
        time.sleep(1)

        sql = "INSERT INTO Arduino_Data(Temperature, Humidity, RPM, Distance) VALUES (%f, %f, %f, %d)"  %(x, y, z, v) 

        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit

        break
```

Comment: Why is your entire script inside quotes?

Comment: Apologies, that was me misunderstanding the formatting system, I tried to format it as '''code'''. Shadow edited it to fix it for me.

Comment: You should allow `cursor.execute()` to substitute parameters, rather than using string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit is a function, you are not calling it :)

```
conn.commit()
```

That should do it

Comment: Thank you so much, i had an inkling it was something daft.